# Exploring congruences and identities involving Mersenne primes and the terms of Lucas-Lehmer test

Tags: proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, primality-test

When I was exploring congruences$\dagger$ involving the terms $S_k$ defined in [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) (this reference is the **Wikipedia**, but the main reference is **Crandall** and **Pomerance**, Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective Springer(2001)) I've said to me that perhaps could be an interesting idea to combine relations that satisfies the **sum of divisors function** $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ and some of the terms of the sequence $S_k$ defined in the **Lucas-Lehmer test**.

I believe that is right and that can deduce easily (if my computations were rigths, from a easy manipulation of the identities $S_{p-1}=S^2_{p-2}-2$ and $S_{p}=S^2_{p-1}-2$) that on assumption that $M_p=2^p-1$ is a **Mersenne prime** (a fixed Mersenne prime) with $p>2$ then $$S_{p}\equiv 2\text{mod}M_p,$$ thus since $M_p$ is prime one has that $$\text{gcd}(S_{p},M_p)=1,$$ and from this, since the sum of divisors function is **multiplicative** then (**here was fixed a mistake, thanks to the user in comments**)$$\sigma(S_pM_p)=\sigma(S_p)2^p.$$

> **Question 1.** Were rights my computations?

On assumption that $\text{gcd}(\sigma(S_{p}),M_p)=1$, also one could do a nested calculation $$\sigma(\sigma(S_pM_p)-\sigma(S_p))=\sigma(\sigma(S_p))2^p.$$

> **Question 2.** What's about this condition $\text{gcd}(\sigma(S_{p}),M_p)=1$, when $M_p$ is a Mersenne prime with $p>2$? Can you find a counterexample for this condition?

Feel free if there are mistakes to do the corrections. **Many thanks.**

$\dagger$ **Appendix:** It is possible to get a lot of such conguences by reproducing the shape of a Mersenne prime, using the identity (identities) involving Lucas-Lehmer test for a fixed Mersenne prime $M_p$ with $p>2$, Euler-Fermat theorem, and the Newton binomial theorems for specials sums or products, and after dividing by $M_p=2^p-1$. You are welcome if you want to explore and ask about these simple and complicated identities.

Comment: $\sigma(S_p)=\sigma(S_p)2^p$ cannot be valid unless $\sigma(S_p)=0$ or $2^p=1.$ which is not possible. Please check your equation.

Comment: @gammatester thanks for your help and attention, was fixed this mistake.

Comment: [the LL test says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Proof_of_correctness) $S_{p-2} \equiv 0 \bmod M_p$ iff $M_p$ is prime (considering simple group theory facts about the units of $(\mathbb{Z}+\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z} \bmod M_p, \times)$). why would you care of $gcd(S_{p},M_p)$ and of $\sigma(S_p)$ ?

Comment: THere is no mathematical meaning, I write a lot of identities, and after I was tired. Thus if you can add or study on your home a best approach, it is the best. There is a problem with $S_{p-2}$, $M_p$ versus the sum of divisor function that, is that these numberes are no relatively prime. Merci @user1952009

Comment: if you are not sure of something, test yourself on matlab/mathematica, or take one week for thinking about it, you can't come here for checking everything you wrote (it won't be useful for you nor for us)

Comment: You are right, I think it. Very thanks much @user1952009